# Website scrolls up automatically when clicked on input box only in android mobile phones

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, input, textarea

I developed a website using React and added a contact form at the end. When the website is viewed in android mobile phones, there is a bug. If user clicks on any input box or text area, website automatically scrolls up.
I have not added any link or anchor tag to input boxes still it behaves unexpectedly. I searched on the issue and it is something related to bug in android native browser, the page resizes when it tries to open soft keyboard. I don't face the same issue when site is being viewed on Laptop or ios devices.

Here's link to the website:
https://dronzer03.github.io/athang-portfolio/

Edit:

I fixed the bug by adding following in code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Athang";

    setTimeout(function () {
      var viewheight = window.innerHeight;
      var viewwidth = window.innerWidth;
      var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
      viewport.setAttribute(
        "content",
        "height=" +
          viewheight +
          "px, width=" +
          viewwidth +
          "px, initial-scale=1.0"
      );
    }, 300);
  }, []);
```

If you want to see fixed website:
You can go to:
https://athang.netlify.app

Code:

```
                <div>
                  <h4>Leave me a message or feedback:</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="form">
                  <div>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <input id="name" value={from} onChange={changeFrom} onFocus={onFocusChange} />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <input id="mail" value={email} onChange={changeEmail} />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>Message/Feedback:</label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <textarea id="msg" value={msg} onChange={changeMsg} />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <Button className="btns" onClick={sendMail}>
                      Send
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```